# "about:blank#blocked" error while i submit my html form

Tags: html, node.js, forms, tags

Here is the code

```
<form action="127.0.0.1:1337" method="POST">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname" value=""><br><br>
  Last name:<input type="text" name="lname" value=""><br><br>
  Email:<input type="email" name="email" value=""><br><br>
  Comment:<textarea cols=20 rows=10 name="comment"></textarea><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn">
</form>
```

but the form is not being submitted to the action address.

Comment: Kindly post node.js code part also.

Comment: Add http:// to your url.

Comment: Voting to close as the problem is caused by a typo (the URL is missing a scheme)

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: @Quentin even after adding labels form has not been submitted, adding "http" in action has resolved the problem thanks for the solution :)

Comment: @Noob_developer — Pointing out the missing label elements was a criticism of the code, not a solution to the stated problem.

Comment: @Quentin i am new to stackoverflow and coding as well i am not understanding voting,OP Block and all, even from your criticism ill start learning thanks for that as well